# How can I load 10,000 rows of test.xls file into mysql db table?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

How can I load 10,000 rows of test.xls file into mysql db table?

When I use below query it shows this error.

LOAD DATA INFILE 'd:/test.xls' INTO TABLE karmaasolutions.tbl_candidatedetail (candidate_firstname,candidate_lastname);

[image]

My primary key is candidateid and has below properties.

[image]

The test.xls contains data like below.
[image]

I have added rows starting from candidateid 61 because upto 60 there are already candidates in table.

please suggest the solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import data from Excel (or any other program that can produce a text file) is very simple using the LOAD DATA command from the MySQL Command prompt.

> Save your Excel data as a csv file (In Excel 2007 using Save As) Check
>   the saved file using a text editor such as Notepad to see what it
>   actually looks like, i.e. what delimiter was used etc. Start the MySQL
>   Command Prompt (I’m lazy so I usually do this from the MySQL Query
>   Browser – Tools – MySQL Command Line Client to avoid having to enter
>   username and password etc.) Enter this command: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
>   ‘C:\temp\yourfile.csv’ INTO TABLE database.table FIELDS TERMINATED
>   BY ‘;’ ENCLOSED BY ‘”‘ LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\r\n’ (field1, field2);
>   [Edit: Make sure to check your single quotes (') and double quotes (")
>   if you copy and paste this code - it seems WordPress is changing them
>   into some similar but different characters] Done! Very quick and
>   simple once you know it :)

Some notes from my own import – may not apply to you if you run a different language version, MySQL version, Excel version etc…

TERMINATED BY – this is why I included step 2. I thought a csv would default to comma separated but at least in my case semicolon was the deafult
ENCLOSED BY – my data was not enclosed by anything so I left this as empty string ”
LINES TERMINATED BY – at first I tried with only ‘\n’ but had to add the ‘\r’ to get rid of a carriage return character being imported into the database
Also make sure that if you do not import into the primary key field/column that it has auto increment on, otherwhise only the first row will be imported

Original [Author reference](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2008/02/import-excel-data-into-mysql-in-5-easy.html)

Answer (score 4):

Export your Excel spreadsheet to CSV format.

Import the CSV file into mysql using a similar command to the one you are currently trying:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'd:/test.csv'
INTO TABLE karmaasolutions.tbl_candidatedetail 
(candidate_firstname,candidate_lastname);
```

Comment: I am getting below error while executing the above query.
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘d:\Karmaa_load_data_test.csv’ INTO TABLE karmaasolutions.tbl_candidatedetai' at line 1"

Comment: You're using a weird apostrope quote. replace it with a fimple `'`. Also try double backslashes in the path